# Chartjs labels position

Tags: chart.js

At any point I will only have 2 labels, min and max. I would like to bring in the labels like in the design. I have tried `mirror` but that will affect both min and max. The only way I can think of doing this is by using positioned divs to make it look like labels

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Current: [image: What I have now]
Expected: [image: What I am after]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could define [`options.scales.xAxis.offset = true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-configuration), this adds extra space to both edges and the axis is scaled to fit into the chart area.

```
options: {
  ...
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      offset: true,
      ...
    }],
  }
}
```